# Compare-Object Format Output

Tags: powershell

And this is my output `EmailBody variable`:

```
TEST GROUP --- @{InputObject=User01; SideIndicator==>}TEST GROUP --- @{InputObject=User02; SideIndicator==>}
```

Here is the kind of output I am looking for `EmailBody variable` as     top and bottom :

```
TEST GROUP --- User01 added to mail group.
TEST GROUP --- User02 added to mail group.
```

Is it possible for me to format my output? I only want to display custom keyword instead of  `@{InputObject=User01; SideIndicator==>}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the script that I wrote:

```
$EmailBody = ""

$Groups = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\MyGroups.txt"

$Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_
    $infoMember = Get-AdgroupMember "$Group" -Recursive
    $Members = foreach ($member in $infoMember) { get-aduser $member.samaccountname -properties displayname | select -ExpandProperty displayname  }

    if (!(Test-Path "C:\temp\$Group.txt"))
    {
     New-Item -path "C:\temp\$Group.txt" -type "file"
     Write-Host "Created new file"
     $Members | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\$Group.txt" -Force
    }
    else{
    $OldMembers = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\$Group.txt"        
    $Change = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $OldMembers -DifferenceObject $Members
     ForEach($Changes in $Change) {
          if ($Changes.sideindicator -eq "=>") {              
            if ($Changes){
            $EmailBody += "$Group`n---`n$Changes"
            }
          write-host "user added to mail group"  -ForegroundColor Cyan
          $Members | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\$Group.txt" -Force
          }
          else{
          write-host "nothing"  -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: $changes will be an object with properties. You need to access a specific property of that object. You will need to use $($changes.InputObject) within your email body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to address your issue. The solution without modifying the rest of your code is to access the `InputObject` property of your `Compare-Object` output. Since you will be accessing a custom object property while inside of a string, you will need to use the subexpression operator (`$()`).

```
$EmailBody += "$Group`n---`n$($Changes.InputObject)"
```

If you do not use the subexpression operator, `$Changes.InputObject` expansion will stop at the `.` character resulting in only `$Changes` still being interpolated. The output would then be a hash table with the string `.InputObject` appended to the end.

---

An alternative that reduces complexity is to just use a `Where-Object` comparison. You won't need to do the `SideIndicator` comparison now. If `$change` contains any data, then you know there were differences.

```
$change = $members | Where-Object {$_ -notin $oldmembers}
if ($change) {
    $EmailBody = $change | Foreach-Object { 
                     "$Group`n---`n$_"
                 }
}
```

---

The issue with your attempt is the default `Compare-Object` output returns a custom object with properties `InputObject` and `SideIndicator`. If you attempt to output a custom object with properties as a string, it will return a hash table of your properties. See below for an example.

```
$change = Compare-Object  -ReferenceObject $members -DifferenceObject $oldmembers
$change

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
user1       <=
user3       <=

foreach ($changes in $change) {
    "the output is $changes"
}
the output is @{InputObject=user1; SideIndicator=<=}
the output is @{InputObject=user3; SideIndicator=<=}
```